# Github pushing commits to different folder structure

Tags: git, github, directory

Suppose I have a local repository with folder structure like this:

```
ProjectName
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── projectname
                └── subfoldername
                    ├── File1User1.java
                    ├── File2User1.java
                    ├── ...
                    └── FileNUser1.java
```

While I want a folder structure on github repository to be like this:

```
ProjectName
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── projectname
                └── subfoldername
                    ├── tasks1
                    │   ├── File1User1.java
                    │   ├── File1User2.java
                    │   ├── ...
                    │   └── File1UserK.java
                    ├── tasks2
                    │   ├── File2User1.java
                    │   ├── File2User2.java
                    │   ├── ...
                    │   └── File2UserK.java
                    ├── ...
                    └── tasksN
```

So, as you can see, I have `N` tasks and `K` people who solve those tasks and push their files to a repository. There is no need for those people to create a separate folder for each tasks on their computers, because for them, 1 task = 1 file. However, to better organize tasks and users who've solved those tasks, git repository should have a separate folder for each task.

Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: I don't see how exactly you can achieve that but maybe Git Sub modules may take to closer to what you're trying to achieve. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: You can't. Use separate branches or forks of the main repository as per @AhamadQureshi answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think using branches would be a better option to go with it has many advantages over committing the code in the main branch

Comment: Or, similarly, having each user fork the main repository.